# Why my local website display Apache2 Test Page?

Tags: apache, browser

I've setup my apache server on Centos 6.4 . But when i run my page, browse displayed Apache test page, What wrong i did? 
In /var/www/vhosts/testing.page, my file "index.php" is:

```
<?php
echo 'Welcome, Trien';
?>
```

My virtual host: 
![virtual host][1]

And my page displayed:
![Browse display][2]

Any help?
thank

Answer (score 0):

Delete the index.htm or index.html if exist.

Also, check the permission for the file, make sure it has 'execute' permission.